# VB.NET DataGridView me añade una columna vacía

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

Estoy usando este código para un DataGridView:

```
Public Class Scan
    Private Sub Scan_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        col.DataPropertyName = "PropertyName"
        col.HeaderText = "SomeText"
        col.Name = "colWhateverName"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Me añade una columna en blanco automáticamente que no quiero tener en el datagridview:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como quito esa columna?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si es que logré entender tu problemática. Tendrías que cambiar la propiedad `RowHeadersVisible`  de tu `DataGridView` , para ello en el evento **Load** coloca:

```
dataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = False
```

Donde `dataGridView` lo deberías cambiar por el nombre que le has asignado a tu DataGridView.

Comment: Me explico muy mal, lo sé! Mil disculpas! Me ha funcionado perfectamente, muchas gracias!